# Cordova Android 6 GPS in Background Mode

Tags: android, cordova, background, gps

My cordova app needs to get the GPS position and send it to the server immediatly. 
To accomplish this I use Apache plugin `cordova-plugin-device-motion` and https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode to keep my application running in the background.

This works great on Android 4.x and 5.x but I cannot get the GPS position on Android 6 while the app is in background.

To make things clearer I created a new empty cordova app, added those two plugins and wrote this code to check where the error might be. The accelerometer is just for checking if the application is still running and has access to the device's sensors.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

            var watchIDAcceleration = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccessAccelerometer, onErrorAccelerometer, { frequency: 5000 });

            var watchIDPosition = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessGPS, onErrorGPS);

            /*setInterval(function() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessGPS, onErrorGPS);
            }, 5000)*/

        }, false);

        /*
        ACCELEROMETER Callbacks
         */
        function onSuccessAccelerometer(acceleration) {
            console.log('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
        }

        function onErrorAccelerometer() {
            console.log('onError!');
        }

        /*
        GPS Callbacks
         */
        function onSuccessGPS(position) {
            console.log( 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude +
                         'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude);

        }

        function onErrorGPS(error) {
            console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
```

The console output for this is:
[image: Console output for code during foreground and background]

As you can see while the application is in background the GPS callbacks are no longer called. And when the application gets back to foreground the are all called at one time.

I checked both the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` as well as the `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()` while the other one was commented out. Both times I got the same endresult.

At first I guessed it might have something to do with the doze mode in Android 6 but it doesn't seem to be the problem as the accelerometer data still gets printed to the console. But to be sure I disabled doze mode in the settings for this app. GPS permissions were also granted at runtime.

I'm running cordova 6.3.0 and was mainly testing this on an real Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 6.0.0. But it doesn't work with virtual devices (Genymotion) on Android 6 either. Both plugins are in the latest version which is 0.6.4 for the background plugin and 2.2.0 for the geolocation plugin.

Comment: try this plugin it works well https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt